# R Incorrectly Returning Infinity

Tags: r, math

In R I am trying to convert some values to the power -0.5. Some of my values are 0, and they return Inf when I do this. Why is that the case? Unless I'm having some obvious lapse in math knowledge, 0 to the power of anything is still 0, which is what I'm expecting.

My values are in the 1000's range, and they return proper results (i.e. 1000^(-0.5) = 0.031)

Am I doing something obviously wrong? Is there something special I need to do in R? Here's a sample of my code:

`DF[grep(".SUFFIX", names(henn))] <- DF[grep(".SUFFIX", names(DF))]^(-0.5)`

The code works fine btw for other functions, like if I did `+ 10`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer. 0 to any positive power is 0, 0 to any negative power is undefined (dividing by 0). It makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting Infinity because raising 0 to a negative power results in dividing by 0:

```
0 ^ (-0.5) =
1 / (0^(0.5)) =
1 / 0 = Infinity
```